# TIdHTTP GET Round Trip Request/Response Time in MSecs

Tags: c++builder, indy, indy10, idhttp

I'm using TIdHTTP to make HTTP GET requests to get wiki pages (executed until x >= 9 times using a for loop statement).

I am trying to use TStopWatch to measure the HTTP round trip request/response time in milliseconds of each GET requests.

I have tried somes methods, but, I still in doubt that it was right or not. So, please tell me what's the right method to do that. Thank you.

Btw, the code I have is:

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  int MSec = 0;
  TTimeSpan TTSpan;
  TDateTime StartTime;
  DWORD AStartTime = 0;
  DWORD CStartTime = 0;
  String ACount, Codes, Milli, Result;

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner) : TForm(Owner)
{
  IdHTTP->ConnectTimeout = 3048;
  IdHTTP->ReadTimeout = 2048;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::IdHTTPWork(TObject *ASender, TWorkMode AWorkMode, __int64 AWorkCount)
{
  if (AWorkMode == wmRead)
    ACount = "size: [" + String(AWorkCount) + " bytes]";
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::WorkClick(TObject *Sender)
{
  static int Number = 1;
  TStopwatch SWatch = TStopwatch::StartNew();

  // CStartTime = GetTickCount();
  // DWORD Start = timeGetTime();
  // AStartTime = GetTickCount();
  // CStartTime = TTSpan.Milliseconds;

  Work->Enabled = false;
  ListBox->Items->Clear();
  ListBox->Items->BeginUpdate();

  for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
  {
    try
    {
      SWatch.Start();
      try
      {
        IdHTTP->Get("http://en.wikipedia.org/");
        Sleep(1000);
      }
      catch (const Exception &E)
      {
        Label1->Caption = E.Message;
      }

      SWatch.Stop();
      TTSpan = SWatch.Elapsed;
      MSec = TTSpan.Milliseconds;
      // MSec = TTSpan.Milliseconds / 10;
      // MSec = SWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds / 10;
      // TTSpan = SWatch.Elapsed;
      // MSec = TTSpan.Milliseconds - CStartTime;

      Milli = " time: [" + String(MSec) + " ms]";
      Codes = " code: [" + IdHTTP->Response->ResponseText.LowerCase() + "]";
      ListBox->Items->Add("(" + String(Number++) + "). " + ACount + Codes + Milli);

      // AStartTime = GetTickCount();
      // ListBox->Items->Add("(" + String(Number++) + "). " + ACount + Codes + Result.sprintf(L" time: [%i ms]",(aStartTime-bStartTime)));
    }
    __finally
    {
      Work->Enabled = true;
      IdHTTP->Disconnect(true);
      ListBox->Items->EndUpdate();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: For one thing, your `Sleep()` should not be included in the time you are clocking. Call `SWatch.Start()` *immediately* before `IdHttp->Get()`, then `SWatch.Stop()` *immediately* after, THEN do the rest of your work as needed. The call to `Sleep()` should be at the end of the loop iteration, not in the middle of it. Personally, I would not use a sleeping loop in the main UI thread, I would use a `TTimer` instead, or move the loop to a worker thread.

Comment: Okay, I have changed my codes and it works perfectly. Thank you very much, Remy!.

Comment: Just note that even this approach is not clocking *just* the network traffic by itself, it is clocking *everything* that `Get()` does internally (which is a lot), including preparing the request, sending the request, receiving the response, parsing the response, and handling any intermediate HTTP redirect responses/requests that may be used before the final response is sent. If you want to clock *just* the network traffic by itself, that gets more involved.